# generate file content with nginx

Tags: nginx

We are running a repository on `nginx` (publishing static files that can be downloaded via https).

The repository looks something like this:

```
.../www/
.../www/repo/
.../www/repo/some-files
.../www/repo/README.txt
.../www/repo-latest/
.../www/repo-latest/some-files
.../www/repo-latest/README.txt
.../www/other-files
```

And the contents of the `README.txt` files are basically always the same, differing only in the URL, e.g.:

```
This is `README.txt`. Download the file from `https://www.some-web.com/repo/some-files`
```

where the URL is based on the location of the `README.txt` file.

I would like to create the `README.txt` file dynamically, so that I don't have to change several files each time the content changes.

I would be most comfortable with adding a list of folders to the configuration that should generate a `README.txt` based on the contents of a template.

Does `nginx` have this capability, or is there some tool (e.g. JS) to achieve this?

As a complete novice with `nginx` I am a bit lost and have not been able to find a satisfactory answer. I will be glad for any answer including links to documentation and such. I don't even know properly what I should be looking for.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is a bit verbose because I'm generalizing over a solution I recently had to come up with.

```
location ~ README.txt {
    set $readme 'This is `README.txt`...';
    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    return 200 $readme;
}
```

Breakdown:

1. `set $readme...` is not required. You can just `return` the string, but I imagine you'll be appending the url in your readme relative to the accessed `location`
2. `add_header Content-Type...` may not be necessary depending on defaults but it's better to be explicit